# Android JSONObject.getString() scrambles large numbers

Tags: android, json, phone-number

When I try to send JSONObject from server I have number **00420123456789** like phone number (but saved in DB and sent from the server as string!!)

When I get it in android it is in JSONObject shortened to **420123456789** it is no problem for me I can add two more zeros at the beginning

**BUT**

when I try `String s = JSONObject.getString("myNumber")` it returns 4.20607238118E11.

Can somebody tell me anything to this?? I don't know what to do tried a lot of google searching but it looks like no one is sending long numbers in JSON.

**EDIT:**
shortened and changed personal data but this is JSON I am receiving:

```
{
        Id: 1,
        name: myName,
        city: Prague,
        street: Karlovarska,
        street_number: 48,
        postal_code: 50280,
        phone_number: 420123456789,
        email: email@email.com,
        webpage: www.aaa.com/page.aspx,
    }
```

another problem appeared: in JAVA(android) using

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStringFromWeb);
```

everything works until I send webpage with "/" I tried escaping by // or / but nothing works...

Comment: only working thing for me now is String.valueOf(JSONObject.getLong("myNumber"))

Comment: Please show the JSON that you are parsing.

Comment: I edited my question, added my JSON and added another problem i have with parsing URL

Answer (score 2):

Change the JSON to make `phone_number` be a string, not an integer:

```
{ Id: 1, name: myName, city: Prague, street: Karlovarska, street_number: 48, postal_code: 50280, phone_number: "420123456789", email: email@email.com, webpage: www.aaa.com/page.aspx, }
```

After all, not all phone numbers in the world are integers.

Similarly, `street_number` and `postal_code` should be strings, as not all street numbers (`221B`) or postal codes (most of them in the UK) are integers.

Comment: it looks nice but, the response i am receiving from server generates automatically IHttpActionResult Ok, so i can not change it so easily and in database I have phone_number  set as varchar,

Comment: @JiříStrakoš: Regardless, your problems are in your JSON. Fix the JSON, and your Android problems will solve themselves.

Comment: I tried now to simulate POST from firebug and returned Json is in good format so finally I found that it was my mistake because when I read response from API in java I did replace on quotes...

Answer (score 0):

When you put into the long type, it may lead to this situation, you can pass in the incoming String type. like this：

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
json.put("myNumber",420123456789.toString())
```